# Empty regex group when using OR?

Tags: javascript, regex

When using the regex `^\[(.*?)\]$|(.*)` in javascript, an empty group (`undefined`) is created. I am guessing this is due to the OR attempting the first match and creating an empty group if it fails, or visa versa with the second group. Is there any way to make it so that only one group is returned when using regex.exec(string) in javascript?

My test code is the following;

```
var regex = /^\[(.*?)\]$|(.*)/;

console.log(regex.exec("[test]")); // ["[test]", "test", undefined]
console.log(regex.exec("test")); // ["test", undefined, "test"]
```

Comment: A "solution" : `console.log(regex.exec("[test]").slice(1).join(''))`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that ? You know you can do `result[1]||result[2]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why are you even using a regex for the second group when it matches the entire input?

```
var input = '[test]',
    match = input.match(/^\[(.*?)\]$/),
    result = match? match[1] : input;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I realised this after posting. Accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything in yet one group:

```
var regex = /^(\[(.*?)\]$|(.*))/;
regex.exec("[test]")
> ["[test]", "[test]", "test", undefined]
regex.exec("test")
> ["test", "test", undefined, "test"]
```

the result will always be the group 1.

To get rid of inner groups, make them non-capturing:

```
> var regex = /^(\[(?:.*?)\]$|(?:.*))/;
regex.exec("[test]")
> ["[test]", "[test]"]
regex.exec("test")
> ["test", "test"]
```

Comment: Why would you wrap the entire expression in one group? That’s the same as group 0.

Comment: @minty: if this case, yes, but if `a|b` is a part of a bigger expr, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can make square brackets optional in your regex:

```
^\[?(.*?)\]?$
```

And have everything in `match group #1`

Comment: @dystroy: OP's regex `^\[(.*?)\]$|(.*)` will also match string `[test`

Comment: @dystroy: Actually I didn't intend to have outside parentheses but mistyped it. Corrected it now. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that the *or* part of the expression was never needed.